# ¿Es correcto este add() con un AVLTree de pares?

Tags: java

Me han proporcionado este código de java en el que usan una estructura `TreeMap<>()` para añadir valores, y he intentado recrear el código usando un AVLTree de pares y quería saber si es correcto o no.
El ejercicio se basa en añadir un *autorID* y una colección de artículos, la colección de artículos tiene un *articuloID* y una colección de palabras, y la colección de palabras tiene la palabra y un `Integer` que es las veces que esa palabra está escrita en el artículo. Aquí dejo ambos códigos.

```java
private TreeMap<String, TreeMap <String, TreeMap<String, Integer>>> datos = new TreeMap<>();

public void add(String autorID, String articulosID, String...palabras) {

  TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> aux = datos.get(autorID);

  if (aux == null) {
    datos.put(autorID, aux = new TreeMap<>());
  }

  TreeMap <String, Integer> temp = aux.get(articulosID);

  if (temp == null) {
    aux.put(articulosID, temp = new TreeMap<>());
  }

  for (String palabra: palabras) {
    Integer cont = temp.get(palabra);
    if (cont == null) cont = 0;
    cont++;
    temp.put(palabra, cont);
  }
}
```

Y este es el que he hecho yo.

```java
private AVLTree<Pair<String, Pair<String, Pair<String, Integer>>>> datos = new AVLTree<>();

public void add(String autorID, String articulosID, String...palabras) {

    Pair<String, Pair<String, Pair<String, Integer>>> par = this.datos.find(new Pair<>(autorId, null));

    if (par == null) {
      this.datos.add(par = new Pair<>());
    }

    Pair<String, Pair<String, Integer>> par2 = par1.find(new Pair<>(articulosID, null));

    if (par2 == null) {
      par.add(par2 = new Pair<>());
    }

    for (String palabra: palabras) {
      Pair<String, Integer> par3 = par2.find(new Pair<>(palabra, null));
      if (par3 == null) {
        par2.add(par3 = new Pair<>(palabra, 0);
        }
        par3.getValue().add(par3.getValue() + 1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que preguntar si algo es correcto o no es solicitar opiniones, por lo cual tu pregunta podría terminar [cerrada](/help/closed-questions). ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado en ambos casos? ¿Cuál es el obtenido? ¿Hay errores de ejecución en alguno de los códigos?

Comment: Por cierto, los snippets están reservados para códigos HTML/CSS/JS ejecutables en la pregunta. Java no está soportado en los snippets.